# Can Apache be setup as forward proxy and reverse proxy at the same time?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to achieve the following:

My app services user requests like so:
user request www.mysite.com -> Apache reverse proxy -> 192.168.1.1:8080/myApp

My app also makes requests but I want to route through a proxy:
192.168.1.1:8080/myApp -> Apache forward proxy -> www.google.com

Can I set this up on the same Apache server? If not, can I do it with two Apache servers on the same system?

Comment: Did you find and answer?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set up two virtual hosts in apache with different ports, one acting as a reverse proxy and the other, a forward proxy.

Answer (score 0):

One conf file contains `ProxyRequest on` which makes Apache work as Forward-proxy and put ProxyRemote to `localhost:high-port`, and another conf file contains VHOST block for each port with `ProxyRequest off` which make Apache as `Reverse-proxy`.